# Switch between 3 or more css classes during a php foreach loop

Tags: css, foreach

We've been switching between an odd/even classes during a foreach loop like this:

```
<?php
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($pages as $page) { ?>

   <div class="row <php echo (++$count%2 ? "odd" : "even") ?>">
     ...page_list or product_list output
   </div>

<php } ?>
```

But how would we switch between 3 or more css classes?

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If else statements can be used and make sure to change the mod number.

Try this:

```
        <div class="row 
    <php
        ++$count;
        if($count % 3 == 0)
        {
            echo "style2";
        }
        else if($count % 3 == 1)
        {
            echo "style2";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "style3";
        }
    ?>
    ">
    ...page_list or product_list output
    </div>

<php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put them into an array and use the modulo operator:

```
<?php
  $count = 0;
  $classes = array('one', 'two', 'three');

  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $count = ++$count % count($classes);
    $class = $classes[$count];
  ?>

   <div class="row <?php echo $class ?>">
     ...
   </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the same structure, you could nest ternaries.

```
echo (++$count%3==0 ? "3" : ($count%3==1 ? "3+1" : "3+2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

if the array key pair is numeric, you could just use a foreach loop with a key => value output and evaluate the key with the [numbulus operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). then use the result in a [switch statement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

if the array keys are not numeric you could set a variable before the foreach loop and increment it with every itteration and check for its value..

```
<?php
$pages = Array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');

foreach ($pages as $key => $page) :

  switch ( $key % 3 ) { (3 is the number of available cases)
    case 0:
      $class = 'class1';
      //…
      break;
    case 1:
       $class = 'class2 foo';
       //…
      break;
    case 2:
      $class = 'bar';
      //…
      break;
  endswitch;

  echo '<div class="' . $class . '">';
  //…
  echo '</div>';

endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way switching multiple css is by using

[Control Structure Switch Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 0):

having `class1`, `class2` and `class3`

```
<?php
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $count = $count == 3 ? 0 : $count++;
?>
   <div class="row <?php echo "class".$count ?>">
     ...page_list or product_list output
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```